# Is there a way in Pandas to merge two dataframes using columns that are modified without affecting the originals?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to merge two dataframes on columns that contain names that match minus their capitalization. The base object has a "title" format, whereas the merging object is in an "upper" format.

I could easily modify the merging object to a "title" format and then merge, but is it possible to effectively do this temporarily without formally modifying the original dataframe? I could also just make a copy and modify that, but I'm aiming for the simplest solution with the fewest extra dataframes.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['John', 'Mary', 'Louis'],
                    'value': np.random.randint(0,100,3)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['MARY', 'JOHN', 'LOUIS'],
                    'value2:': np.random.randint(0,100,3)})

# What I don't want to have to do:
df2['name'] = df2['name'].str.title()
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = 'name')

# What I want to be able to do (doesn't work)

'''
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on = 'name', right_on = title('name'))
'''
```

Comment: Try to enclose sample data and example result please to enable understanding problem.

Comment: `title = lambda df, column: df[column].str.title()
pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on = 'name', right_on = title(df2, 'name'))`

Comment: @RakeshV it's hard to follow this due to formatting. Do you mind reposting it as an answer? I'm assuming this is on two lines, but can't be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['John', 'Mary', 'Louis'],
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['John', 'Mary', 'Louis'],
                    'value': [1,2,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['MARY', 'JOHN', 'LOUIS'],
                    'value2': [10,20,30]})

df1.merge(df2, left_on='name', right_on=df2['name'].str.title()).drop(
            ["name_x", "name_y"], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    name    value   value2
0   John    1       20
1   Mary    2       10
2   Louis   3       30
```

Comment: That's effectively what I'm looking for. I guess I was hoping there would be a less convoluted approach, but it might just not be that useful. How do you normally handle this? Simply deal with the temporary copy, or modify the original column?

Comment: I have updated the answer. I think we will need atleast one copy.

Comment: This is really good. Thanks for figuring it out, I didn't realize I could merge on the temporary df column.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this: -

```
title = lambda df, column: df[column].str.title() 
pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on = 'name', right_on = title(df2, 'name')).drop(['name_x','name_y'], axis = 1)
```